# Stripping hg date

Tags: mercurial, windows-xp

When using

```
hg log --template "{date|isodate} --- {rev}:{node|short} --- ... "

2011-10-07 19:25 -0400 --- 1:c608cbb9aaa3 --- ...
```

what is the easiest way to strip the timezone (-0400) part out? I just want the date and time in the above format without the timezone.

*"..." are the rest of the template/log message. Pay no attention to them.*

Also, what is generally the best way to go about when one wants to modify the log output text a bit further?

Answer (score 1):

None of the **[template filter](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/customizing-the-output-of-mercurial.html#sec%3atemplate%3afilter)** (shortdate, isodate, rfcdate,... [full list here](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Theming#Filters)) proposes the kind of output your are after.

So some kind of output filtering must be involved (awk, sed, cut, ...), like (not tested)

```
hg log --template "{date|isodate} --- {rev}:{node|short} --- ... " |  sed 's/-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] //g')
```